# Structure & maintain a Golang project with multiple files

Tags: api, go, structure

I'm currently discovering Golang and I'm currently playing with Mux and Gorm to try to build an API.

So everything is fine until the point where I have too much content in my main.go file so I want to split this API into multiple files,

Naturally, like I would do in a Node.js API, I create a models Folder, and a routes folder, and begin to put my Models in individual files in the models folder (model1.go, model2.go etc) to have a structure like:

`/MyProject
   |main.go
   |/models
      |model1.go
      |model2.go`

Then I google a bit (well, a lot now..) to know how to include them in my main.go file, and now i'm facing the fact that in Golang the design of **the language wants that any external file is a package** which may be used by any other golang app, which is not what I'm looking for, **I just want to split the content of my project to have a better maintainability** but it seems to be impossible with that project design in mind.
I heard about vendoring since 1.6 but that's still not a solution cause that's make necessary to keep the dependencies and the project files at the same place, which is not a conventional (and logical) way to structure a project

I guess heavy and complex Golang projects don't have their entire code base into one single file so **I'm just looking for the good way to structure a project into multiple files** like they would do to maintain their projects.

Comment: If you want your code in the same package, then just don't put files in other  directories.

Comment: I suggest take a look at this. It shows the standard structure of a package (though not wildly adopted). Many Go tools (from Google) follow the same convention. And it has semantics like when a package from `internal/pkg` is referred inside another project, Go compiler will show an error. https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

Comment: "the language wants that any external file is a package" - not true. Each *directory* is a package. Go makes no distinction between *files*. "which may be used by any other golang app" - only if you publish it, and really only if you publish it and say "this is for people to use for XYZ". If you post *any* code publicly, someone else might use it; but if you don't say it's for others to use, then they shouldn't expect fitness for any purpose or support for any issues.

Comment: Also, use `go build` or `go install` to build the executable.

Answer (score 3):

```
/MyProject
   |main.go
   |model1.go
   |model2.go
```

If you want to keep your code in one package only.

Comment: For the moment i'm using this solution with `go run *.go` but that looks like this is more like a trick than a true solution.

Comment: You don't need to exec `go run *.go`, just `go run main.go` should work. Everything under same package don't need import when used in the same package.

Comment: If you need reference, I recommend you to see how others popular go projects organise their structures. For example [gogs](https://github.com/gogits/gogs)

Comment: @MortyChoi The `go run` command creates a package from the files specified on the command line.  The `go run main.go` command will not include model1.go and model2.go in the package.  @Tisamu is correct that `go run *.go` is the needed when using the `go run` command.

Comment: Ya, you are right. `go build` don't need but `go run` need.

Answer (score 2):

**Different Approaches**

***One package*** 
When needed we can put variables in the package scope
[image]

***Two packages***
We will import the code from the second package when needed

[image]

***Three+ packages with package for config variables***
We will import the code from the config package when needed. The config package will hold variables like DB and TPL.

[image]

[image]

FYI: there is no global scope in Go.
You can read more about it at [Alex Edwards Code Organization Article](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access)

Comment: This is a weird structure for a project, I tried the go run *.go tricks with my files declared under the same package in the same folder, but that does not look like the way it meant to be,

Your solution is a bit complicated and it's look like we need to declare things multiple time etc so that's not an intuitive and maintainable solution to me,

If you have example where this is used feel free to share them, i'm curious to see that kind of structure in production.

Thanks for your help anyway. :)

Comment: Sure, you can check out the code here. https://github.com/nehagup/golang-web-dev/tree/master/045-code-organization

Comment: After few testing in my project, I choosed to stay with all files in the same folder, that's simplier to maintain and the multi-package structure you showed is too much complicated to fit with, the logic is very strict and not as manageable as I would want it to be. :/

Comment: For sure you can do it using all the files in the same folder but your question looked more about organized structure used by different organizations. So for small projects it's okay to keep all files in one place.